# Change nullability of overridden function's parameter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am implementing an interface of a third party library(java). I am overriding a function with the following signature:

```
override fun onCallback(name: String?) {

}
```

I can change to the following without the compiler complaining:

```
override fun onCallback(name: String) {

}
```

What is the effect of this? What happens if the underlying library calls `onCallback(null)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types coming from Java are platform types (in this case, this parameter has a type of `String!`. If the parameter is not annotated in Java, it's up to you to decide whether it can ever have a `null` value, and you have to mark the type of the parameter in Kotlin accordingly. If you mark it as non-nullable, but Java code passes `null` to it, you'll get an exception at runtime - Kotlin generates checks for parameters like this, which you can look at by decompiling the generated bytecode.

Also see the official docs about [null safety and platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) for more detail.

Comment: Ahh ok, (I listened to a talk about platform types just the other week, my brain didn't connect) I guess I applied some wishful thinking; i kinda hoped calls not matching the function would just be filtered away into the nothingness... Don't see how I can avoid the nullcheck now -.-'

Comment: If you want do that, you could make the parameter have a nullable type and then add `name ?: return` as the first line of the function. Since parameters are essentially `val`s , it would be smart cast to the non-nullable type for the rest of the function.