# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting this error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter event`

for the line

`override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent)`

Following is the entire code. This code was originally in java, I converted it to Kotlin using Android Studio, but now I'm getting this error. I tried rebuilding and cleaning the project, but that didn't work.

```
val action = supportActionBar //get the actionbar
action!!.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true) //enable it to display a custom view in the action bar.
action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar)//add the custom view
action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) //hide the title

edtSearch = action.customView.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch) as EditText //the text editor


//this is a listener to do a search when the user clicks on search button
edtSearch?.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
    override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
         Log.e("TAG","search button pressed")  //doSearch()
         return true
        }
     return false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The last parameter can be `null`, as described by the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html#onEditorAction(android.widget.TextView,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)):

> `KeyEvent`: If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null.

So what you have to do is make the Kotlin type nullable to account for this, otherwise the injected `null` check will crash your application when it gets a call with a `null` value as you've already seen it:

```
edtSearch?.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
    override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        ...
    }
})
```

More explanation about platform types in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47480019/4465208).

Comment: Does this code `onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent)` insert IDE? If so, that's an error of IDE...

Answer (score 17):

For me, it happened with the spinner adapter item selector.
Below is the correct code for this.

```
rootView.spinnerState.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
     }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        }
```

Make sure the adapter & view are allowed to null i.e (?)

Answer (score 6):

To solve this issue, make the `event` parameter nullable, if you use `TextView.OnEditorActionListener`. Add `?` at the end of the declaration:

```
override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?)
```

Answer (score 6):

This error would happen if you pass parameters  with null value from Java class to Kotlin class [by calling methods & implemented callback between classes].

And even pass null to  a parameter that Compiler can not detect it as compile time, so crash will happen in run time.

Because Kotlin is null-safe so the app will crash!

Fix: Change parameters type in kotlin method to Nullable types by adding ? to the end of type.

For example your kotlin funcion will be call in Java class by:

```
//java class file
 ClassKotlin cls = new ClassKotlin()
 cls.function1("name", null, true) //Call func from inside kotlin class
```

but your func declaration in ClassKotlin is:

```
//Kotlin class file
  ClassKotlin {
  fun function1(firstname : String , lastName : String , status : Bool){
  //...
  }
 } // class
```

So you passed a null value to a non Null paremeter in kotlin func.

How to fix:

Just change the Kotlin func as:

```
 fun function1(firstname : String , lastName : String? , status : Boolean){
  //...
  }
```

* a ? added to String data type

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter `title`".

Then researched a function and found a parameter that became `null` while must not:

```
class Item(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val address: String
)
```

When I called it like `Item(id, name, address)` and `name` was `null`, I got this exception.

So, add `?` to all suspecting variables types: `val title: String?`.

Comment: If `title` could be null then you should change the type of `title` to be String?. The `?` indicates that the parameter is a nullable type meaning it may be null. Then when you access it, you need to account for the chance that it is null.

Comment: @SamIAmHarris, sure. I didn't know, that `title` could be `null` (it was gotten from JSON). So, I changed to `String?`. I wrote this answer in order to show how this exception can be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled a bit with this issue, My issue was in the **converters** class provided to the **Room database** class. You can have a closer look into that class and **update the variables** based on their expectancy of **nullability** and **non-nulability**.

Comment: I faced the same issue after adding to Converters it worked, thanks