# Java Parameter specified as non-null is null IllegalException

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

Hi I have Java android application, and integrate stripe and use stripe confirmPayment method. I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849219/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-me)

Comment: hi this question but my project java codes not kotlin

Comment: The error is exactly what the message says, you're passing null into the confirmPayment method and you should not be.

Comment: I think mikeb is right, but would also be interested to see your code here. Can you add that to your question for more context?