# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i m using a progress button library https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/LoadingButtonAndroid  for loginbutton ,when i am trying  to create user by clicking this button in firebase  i got belows errors

i found same error here [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849219/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-me) but i am not  able to get it

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bitmap
    at br.com.simplepass.loadingbutton.customViews.CircularProgressButton.doneLoadingAnimation(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.choudhary.apnidukan.LoginActivity$1$1.onComplete(LoginActivity.java:82)
```

my loginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText email, password, confirmpassword;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    final CircularProgressButton btn = (CircularProgressButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_id);

    email = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
    confirmpassword = findViewById(R.id.edit_confirmPassword);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())) {
                email.setError("Email is must");
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())) {
                password.setError("Password is must");
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmpassword.getText().toString())) {
                confirmpassword.setError("Password not Matched");
                return;
            }

            if (!password.getText().toString().trim().equals(confirmpassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                confirmpassword.setError("Password not matched");
                return;
            }

            String EMAIL = email.getText().toString();
            String PASSWORD = password.getText().toString();
            btn.startAnimation();

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24);

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        btn.doneLoadingAnimation(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, bitmap);
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, mainDrawerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        btn.revertAnimation();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          btn.stopAnimation();
                    }

                }
            });


        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Your call to decodeResource returned null.  Which caused you to pass null into doneLoadingAnimation, which is an error.  That function returns null if it there's an error when trying to load the bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returned **Bitmap** is **null** at `final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24);`. That's why you get error at `btn.doneLoadingAnimation(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, bitmap);`. To get correct `bitmap` from `drawable` you could use below method. Like:

```
    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And call above method inside firebase callback method. Like:

```
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Create Bitmap here------------------
                Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24));
                btn.doneLoadingAnimation(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, bitmap);
                Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, mainDrawerActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            } else {
                btn.revertAnimation();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btn.stopAnimation();
            }

        }
    });
```